# Error Class is public should be declared in a separate file

Tags: java

Am getting the following error, and this error is only showing up on an auto-generated file which shouldn't be edited.

```
error: class CardviewAttributesBinding is public, should be declared in a file named 

CardviewAttributesBinding.java
public final class CardviewAttributesBinding implements ViewBinding {
```

From research, I have found out that this error occurs when there are 2 public java classes in the same file. However there is no class CardviewAttributesBinding.java where I would check for more than one java class except in the auto-generated file. There is no other occurrence of that name/class/file.

Please point me so I can look in the right direction.

Comment: I think you'll get better answers if you could add more information about what tool is autogenerating this file

Comment: What is the data you use as base to generate your code?